# Android.Share to social networks

Tags: android, android-intent, share, social-networking

I am looking a way, how to share just a text to social networks, using android share intents.Almost everyone offers this code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sometext);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using"));
```

but it doesnt work with facebook. Is there any way to share text to all networks. Thanks.

Comment: have you facebook app in your device ..???

Comment: yes, of course. This problem because facebook api doesnt support text, url only.

Answer (score 5):

You can use social network library to post directly to chosen social networks without any code mess

I use [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) it's real simply and can not only post but login or getting friends

**Edit**: as @benka advised I add some code how I made posting to social networks in my app:

Add dependency to chosen social network(facebook and twitter, but ASNE contains more):

```
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.2.1'
...
}
```

Than simply add mSocialNetworkManager from ASNE

```
mSocialNetworkManager = (SocialNetworkManager) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG);
    if (mSocialNetworkManager == null) {
        mSocialNetworkManager = new SocialNetworkManager();
        FacebookSocialNetwork fbNetwork = new FacebookSocialNetwork(this, fbScope);
        mSocialNetworkManager.addSocialNetwork(fbNetwork);
        TwitterSocialNetwork twNetwork = new TwitterSocialNetwork(this, key, secret);
        mSocialNetworkManager.addSocialNetwork(twNetwork);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mSocialNetworkManager, SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG).commit();
    }
```

Than show buttons to share my custom buttons in actionbar menu, and at last check login and use

```
socialNetwork.requestPostMessage("Message");
```

thats all, I need to get friendslist and I just add

```
socialNetwork.requestGetFriends();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @benka, true... I add my expirience

Answer (score 3):

```
public void onShareClick(View v) {
    Resources resources = getResources();

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
    emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    // Native email client doesn't currently support HTML, but it doesn't hurt to try in case they fix it
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_native)));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");


    Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, resources.getString(R.string.share_chooser_text));

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();        
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
        // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
        ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(packageName.contains("android.email")) {
            emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        } else if(packageName.contains("twitter") || packageName.contains("facebook") || packageName.contains("mms") || packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            if(packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_twitter));
            } else if(packageName.contains("facebook")) {
                // Warning: Facebook IGNORES our text. They say "These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice."
                // One workaround is to use the Facebook SDK to post, but that doesn't allow the user to choose how they want to share. We can also make a custom landing page, and the link
                // will show the <meta content ="..."> text from that page with our link in Facebook.
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_facebook));
            } else if(packageName.contains("mms")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_sms));
            } else if(packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_gmail)));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));               
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            }

            intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
        }
    }

    // convert intentList to array
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray( new LabeledIntent[ intentList.size() ]);

    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    startActivity(openInChooser);       
}
```

Comment: what's problem or exception??

Comment: theoretically, this code must share text to all networks, but in practice, it does not work with facebook app.